# problem with HTTPError: Bad Request with urllib.request.urlopen python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a web request in this way:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

 long = 'https://www.elespectador.com/deportes/futbol-colombiano'
 if len(long) < 60:
     data_2 = urllib.request.urlopen(long, context = ctx).read().decode()
```

but i got this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\acer\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in 
http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

 HTTPError: Bad Request
```

I dont know how to deal with this or what is wrong, besides sometimes runs, but only little times.
I need to solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: I am getting HTML content of the page in `data_2` variable. Using python 3.

Comment: yes, but you only get once. Try twice and you'll se probably wont run!!

Comment: Another weird thing, as long as a web page is open in a browser, script able to fetch it, if you close it, then script throws an error like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a loop, wich makes the request too many times until it's donne:

```
long = 'http://www.elcolombiano.com/deportes/futbol-europeo'

while data_0 is None:
contador = contador + 1
try:
    data_0 = urllib.request.urlopen(long, context = ctx).read().decode()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data_0, "html.parser")
    tags_2 = soup2('a')
except:
    print(contador)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle the SSL stuff for you,
but I think it only works in Pip 9 and below:

```
from pip._vendor import requests
link = "https://www.elespectador.com/deportes/futbol-colombiano"    
answer = requests.get(link)
answer_text = answer.text
```

Comment: did it work for you?, tried to install the library but wasn't possible with anaconda!